# Left Join With Multiple results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have a query something like this:

```
Select i.*, prop1.VALUE as PROPERTY_ONE, prop2.VALUE as PROPERTY_TWO
From ITEM i
    Left Join ITEM_PROPERTY prop1 on i.ITEM_ID = prop1.ITEM_D and prop1.PROPERTY_ID = 1 
    Left Join ITEM_PROPERTY prop2 on i.ITEM_ID = prop2.ITEM_D and prop2.PROPERTY_ID = 2
```

Is there any way to only use 1 left join and get all the properties?

Comment: I think, you are doing the same thing. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old style:

```
Select i.*,
       max(decode(prop.PROPERTY_ID,1,prop.VALUE,NULL)) as PROPERTY_ONE,
       max(decode(prop.PROPERTY_ID,2,prop.VALUE,NULL)) as PROPERTY_TWO
  From ITEM i
  Left Join ITEM_PROPERTY prop on i.ITEM_ID = prop.ITEM_D and prop.PROPERTY_ID in(1,2)
 group by there_will_have_to_list_all_the_fields_from_ITEM
```

Or ("light" version, less list in gorup by. But there may be a problem with optimization):

```
Select i.*,prop.PROPERTY_ONE,prop.PROPERTY_TWO
  From ITEM i
  Left Join (
    select ITEM_ID,
           max(decode(PROPERTY_ID,1,VALUE,NULL)) as PROPERTY_ONE,
           max(decode(PROPERTY_ID,2,VALUE,NULL)) as PROPERTY_TWO
      from ITEM_PROPERTY
     where PROPERTY_ID in(1,2)
     group by ITEM_ID
  ) prop on i.ITEM_ID = prop.ITEM_D
```

New style (Oracle 11g+):

```
select * from (
  Select i.*, prop.PROPERTY_ID, prop1.VALUE
    From ITEM i
    Left Join ITEM_PROPERTY prop on i.ITEM_ID = prop.ITEM_D and prop.PROPERTY_ID in(1,2)
)
pivot(
 max(VALUE) for PROPERTY_ID in(1 as "PROPERTY_ONE",2 as "PROPERTY_TWO")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is exactly what I was looking for! Any comment in terms of performance for each query? I was leaning towards the pivot approach.

Comment: @user1292124 Performance depends on many factors. I've been writing that a second request to the idea slowly. But if in "Property" virtually all records with PROPERTY_ID in (1.2) - can be faster than the first query. On the other hand, the Optimizer from Oracle clever, he can do all 3 query lead to a single plan. It is better to look at the execution plans directly on your data

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct then you can get desired result with the following:

```
SELECT i.*, 
    CASE WHEN prop1.PROPERTY_ID = 1 THEN prop1.VALUE ELSE '' END AS  PROPERTY_ONE, 
    CASE WHEN prop1.PROPERTY_ID = 2 THEN prop1.VALUE ELSE '' END AS  PROPERTY_TWO
FROM ITEM i
LEFT JOIN ITEM_PROPERTY prop1 on i.ITEM_ID = prop1.ITEM_D 
AND prop1.PROPERTY_ID IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: This query multiply result rows. Need `group by` and `max/min/sum`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(prop.VALUE) as PROPERTY_VALUE
From ITEM i
Left Join ITEM_PROPERTY prop on i.ITEM_ID = prop.ITEM_D
```

Comment: That's not valid for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select i.*, prop1.VALUE as PROPERTY_ONE, prop2.VALUE as PROPERTY_TWO
    From ITEM i
    Left Join ITEM_PROPERTY prop on i.ITEM_ID = prop.ITEM_D and prop.PROPERTY_ID in (1,2)
```